# ListFragment: переходы назад

Tags: android

Имеется класс, унаследованный от Activity, в который я вставляю ListFragment:

```
public class ListActivity extends Activity {

private FragmentList list;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_list);

    //даём ссылку на контейнер, в который будем вставлять ListFragment
    list = (List) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.container);
    //если layout-файл пустой, то добавляем в него список-фрагмент
    if (list == null){
        list = new List();
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.container, kotlasList).commit();
    }
}
}
```

Также есть класс, унаследованный от ListFragment, который я вставляю в layout-файл, всё стандартно:

```
public class List extends ListFragment {

private ArrayAdapter<String> firstAdapter, secondAdapter;
private String[] firstList = {"One", "Two", "Three"};
private String[] secondList = {"First", "Second", "Third"};

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    firstAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, firstList);
    secondAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, secondList);
    //устанавливаем по умолчанию список из массива firstList
    setListAdapter(firstAdapter);
}

@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    switch (position){
        case 0:
            //если нажат первый пункт списка, то
            //совершаем переход ко второму (показываем второй список - массив secondList)
            setListAdapter(secondAdapter);
            break;
    }
}
}
```

Таким образом имеется 2 списка: `[1] -> [2]`. Как после перехода на второй список мне снова перейти к первому? То есть выполнить обратную операцию: `[2] -> [1]`? Заранее огромное спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте intent:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.example.app.action.list2");
startActivity(intent);
```

Не забудьте добавить интент фильтер для 2 активити в AndroidManifest:

```
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.example.app.action.list2"/>

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    </intent-filter>
```

Comment: Оба списка расположены на одной активити и просто сменяют друг друга. Метод startActivity() здесь не поможет - фрагменты располагаются не на разных активити.